# IE doesn't show all the details from a stylesheet

Tags: css

I have a problem with IE 9 that part of a web site does not show the copyright dates which are in a stylesheet.

It works fine in Firefox.

Is this a problem with IE 9 Or with my settings ?

Antony

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you could show some code samples. The question is a bit vague.

Comment: Yup — without seeing the HTML and CSS, we have no way of knowing what’s going on.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please post related code. If you feel like being extra helpfull, reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link to it.

Comment: The URL is http://www.c5d.co.uk/Untitled2.html

The problem is that after Copyright, the phrase 1999-2011 should appear.

It does on Firefox, but not on IE9.

Is it me ?

I'm not sure how to post code on this site. I got a message saying I couldn't

Thanks

Antony

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your source it becomes clear why you do not see your dates in IE:

```
p.copy::after {
    content: " 1999-2011";
}
```

Internet Explorer does not support the ::after CSS3 psuedo element.

[You can see the CSS supported by all versions of Internet Explorer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. That's answered it then.

Comment: @Antony: No problem.  Be sure to mark it as an answer if you can.